# Find records where field is greater than all values in a set in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table `T1` with columns `C1, C2, C3, C4` and `T2` with columns `C1` and `D1`. I'd like to select all rows in `T1` where appropriate row in `T2` has `D1` greater than `C2`, `C3` and `C4`.

I tried something like this

```
SELECT C1,C2,C3,C4 FROM T1
WHERE (SELECT D1 FROM T2 WHERE C1=T1.C1)>(C2,C3,C4)
```

and this

```
SELECT C1,C2,C3,C4 FROM T1
WHERE (SELECT D1 FROM T2 WHERE C1=T1.C1)>MAX(C2,C3,C4)
```

but what I get is an error in syntax. I could write WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE (SELECT D1 FROM T2 WHERE C1=T1.C1)> C2
 AND  (SELECT D1 FROM T2 WHERE C1=T1.C1)> C3
 AND  (SELECT D1 FROM T2 WHERE C1=T1.C1)> C4
```

However, running the same subquery 3 times is unnecessary for it always returns the same result.

Could anyone help? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function, which allows multiple arguments. MAX() accepts only a single argument, and is intended for aggregate operations

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
...
WHERE T2.D1 > GREATEST(C1,C2,C3,C4)
```

If it helps, MAX() works "vertically", on a single field in a result set. GREATEST() works "horizontally", and operates within a single record.

Comment: Thank you, Marc! GREATEST was exactly what I needed, and explanation with working "horizontally" and "vertically" is very good. : )

Answer (score 1):

Also if I understand correctly, your key is C1... you need to join your tables properly..

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 USING (C1)
WHERE D1 > GREATEST(C2,C3,C4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I put together a little [SQL Fiddle for you here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/163a8/4) and tried to replicate my understanding of what you are asking.

Here is the query I used:

```
SELECT one.* FROM one, two
WHERE (two.frags > one.size)
  AND (two.frags > one.weight)
  AND (two.frags > one.height)
```